# Why my function (marcin) always returns last else?

Tags: javascript, html, calculation

**The script should calculate the price of fuel, depending on its type, but it always returns its last else ("koszt paliwa: 0zł").**

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var rodzaj = document.getElementById("rodzajPaliwa").value;
  rodzaj = parseInt (rozdaj);
  
    var ilosc = document.getElementById("litry").value;
    ilosc = parseInt (ilosc);
    function pierwszyrodzaj(){
        var typ = 4;
        var suma1 = typ*ilosc;
        document.getElementById("koncowacenapaliwa").innerHTML = "koszt paliwa:" + suma1 + "zł";
    }
    function drugirodzaj(){
        var typ = 3.5;
        var suma2 = typ*ilosc;
        document.getElementById("koncowacenapaliwa").innerHTML = "koszt paliwa:" + suma2 + "zł";
    }
    function inny(){
        document.getElementById("koncowacenapaliwa").innerHTML = "koszt paliwa: 0zł";
    }
    
    function marcin (){
        if(rodzaj == '1'){
            pierwszyrodzaj();
        }else if(rodzaj == '2'){
            drugirodzaj();
        }else{
            inny();
        }
        
    }
    
    document.getElementById("oblicz").onclick = marcin;
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>STACJA PALIW</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styl3.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="baner-lewy">
        <h1>Stacja paliw</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="baner-prawy">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="home.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="obliczenia.html">
            <img src="znak.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <main>
        <h3>Oblicz koszt paliwa</h3>

        <label for="rodzajPaliwa">Rodzaj paliwa (1-benzyna, 2-olej napędowy): </label><br>
        <input type="number" name="" id="rodzajPaliwa"><br><br>
        <label for="litry">Ile litrów: </label><br>
        <input type="number" id="litry"><br>
        <br>
        <button id="oblicz" >OBLICZ</button>
    </br>
        <span id="koncowacenapaliwa"></span>
  
        <script src="skrypt.js"></script>
    </main>

    <div id="blok-lewy">
        <a href="kwerendy.txt" download="kwerendy">Pobierz kwerendy</a>
    </div>

    <div id="blok-prawy">
        <img src="samochod.png" alt="samochód">
    </div>
    



    <footer id="">
        <p>&copy; Stronę wykonał: Jan Kupczyk 4TID</p>
    </footer>


  
</body>

</html>
```

[image: That's how the page looks]

some more detailssome more detailssome more detailssome more detailssome more detailssome more detailssome more detailssome more detailssome more detailssome more details

Comment: You should move the declaration of `var rodzaj = document.getElementById("rodzajPaliwa").value;` inside the `marcin` function, otherwise it will use the initial value of the input, which is `""`.